# REGEX to match first occurrence of string only

Tags: php, regex

I'm having troble breaking down a string into an array or matching patterns.
here's the string:

```
Purchased:
12/7/11

58 - $2.5 Gold Coin @ $341.00
290 - Silver Dollar @ $36.02

Total - $500000.00
```

I want to parse this string and return an multi dimensional array like this:

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 58 - $2.5 Gold Coin @ $341.00
        [1] => 290 - Silver Coin @ $36.02  
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 58
        [1] => 290
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => $2.5 Gold Coin
        [1] => Silver Coin
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 341.00
        [1] => 36.02
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => .00
        [1] => .02
    )
)
```

so far I have this:

```
\s*?\n(\d*\.?\d*)\s-\s(.*?)\s\$(\d+(\.\d+)?\.?[0-9]*)
```

But the capturing groups are not working when there is a dollar sign in the product name (ie: '$2.5 Gold Coin')

I'm wondering if there is a way of only getting the amount from strings that start with '@ $'.

I've been using https://regex101.com/ to try and work it out which is an excellent tool but had no joy yet.

Comment: Where did `$36.02` come from?

Comment: You cannot leave out `VF` from the match with a single matching operation. Are you sure of the 0th array in the expected matches?

Comment: Why is `341` missing a `$`

Comment: Silver coin is not in string...

Comment: Could you please write your input and expected output to match and have some sort of logical consistency?

Comment: hey thanks for asking. i'm trying to edit my question

Comment: First impressions matter a lot, fyi. You have 18 views for an incomprehensible example. Most of those people won't return to check for edits and you can expect your post to get no more than 30-50 views on average. I am not trying to be mean, that's just reality.

Comment: Also, check `^(\d*\.?\d+)\s*-\s*(?:VF\s+)?(.*)\s@\s\$(\d+(\.\d+)?)`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/2q5ijI/1)

Comment: Thanks  @WiktorStribiżew that helps. Andreas not so much

Comment: Shall I post my regex as answer?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew. hey sorry for the delay getting back to you. I appreciate your answer. it helped a lot and it definitely the best answer. please post it and i'll give it my recommendation

Comment: @TimFelix I posted the answer, please consider accepting.

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
^(\d*\.?\d+)\s*-\s*(?:VF\s+)?(.*)\s@\s\$(\d+(\.\d+)?)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2q5ijI/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of a string
- `(\d*\.?\d+)` - Group 1: 0+ digits, an optional `.` and 1+ digits
- `\s*-\s*` - `-` enclosed with 0+ whitespaces
- `(?:VF\s+)?` - an optional non-capturing group: `VF` and 1+ whitespaces
- `(.*)` - Group 2: any 0+ chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `\s@\s` - a `@` enclosed with 1 whitespace
- `\$` - a `$` char
- `(\d+(\.\d+)?)` - Group 3: 1 or more digits followed with an optional group 4 matching a dot and then 1+ digits.